# Type script variable is not getting updated in html after calling a function in angular 6

Tags: html, typescript, angular6

Sample program TS:

```
thunderSuperDrop$ = false;
public action = {
    superDropActivate(){
        this.thunderSuperDrop$ = !this.thunderSuperDrop$;
        console.log(this.thunderSuperDrop$);
    }
}
```

HTML :

```
<div class="header-links same-line" 
(click)="action.superDropActivate()"></div>{{thunderSuperDrop$}}
```

Initially the variable thunderSuperDrop$ is set as false and appears in the DOM. Its not getting refreshed after applying the function which works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
superDropActivate(){
    this.thunderSuperDrop$ = true;
    console.log(this.thunderSuperDrop$);
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="header-links same-line" 
(click)="superDropActivate()">{{thunderSuperDrop$}}</div>
```